# Angular universal with firebase functions doesn't work

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I followed the instructions from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE&t=725s) and I implemented the code in my project:

```
import * as angularUniversal from 'angular-universal-express-firebase';

let ssrapp = angularUniversal.trigger({
 index: __dirname + '/index.html',
 main: __dirname + '/main.bundle',
 enableProdMode: true,
 cdnCacheExpiry: 2400,
 browserCacheExpiry: 1200
});
```

but the source code of my webpage is this: [image: Source Code of the webpage]
Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/457

universal stuck
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

Angular waits for all async operations to complete before it renders.
firebase opens and holds open a websocket connection and for Angular to be able to render your application on the server this websocket connection must close, otherwise it will never render.
AngualrFire2 is working to support universal but right now firebase by itself does not

but: An Http request would work fine yeah

Comment: use rest API for firebase to make it universal. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1073